# Inner join and Group By error

Tags: sql, join

I have two tabels :
`tbl_album` and `tbl_gallery`

How can I select the last image of the last three albums?

these are columns of my tables:

```
tbl_album:   Id,al_name
tbl_gallery: Id,album_id,ga_pic_title,ga_file_name
```

I use this query:

```
select al.Id, al.al_name, ga.ga_file_name 
from tbl_album al inner join tbl_gallery ga 
on al.Id=ga.album_id  order by Id desc
```

I receive an error when I used Group By clause:

```
select al.Id, al.al_name, ga.ga_file_name 
from tbl_album al inner join tbl_gallery ga 
on al.Id=ga.album_id group by al.al_name order by Id desc
```

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Column 'tbl_album.Id' is invalid
>   in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate
>   function or the GROUP BY clause.

I do not want to repeat al_name column.

Is there a better way?

Comment: You should tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to include all your column in `select list` to `group by` like below (I think you are using `SQL Server` or `Other` but not `MySQL`). BTW, why do you need a `group by` in your posted query?

```
select al.Id, al.al_name, ga.ga_file_name 
from tbl_album al 
inner join tbl_gallery ga on al.Id=ga.album_id 
group by al.Id, al.al_name, ga.ga_file_name 
order by Id desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Most databases support the `row_number()` function which really helps with what you want to do:

```
select id, al_name, ga_filename
from (select al.Id, al.al_name, ga.ga_file_name,
            row_number() over (partition by al.id order by ga.id desc) as seqnum,
            dense_rank() over (order by al.id desc) as seqnum_album
      from tbl_album al inner join
           tbl_gallery ga
           on al.Id = ga.album_id
     ) t
where seqnum = 1 and seqnum_album <= 3;
```

Note that I used the window function `dense_rank()` to determine the last three albums.  You can also do this with an `order by` and a clause the limits the number of rows.  Unfortunately, the latter depends on the database, so it might be `top 3`, or `limit 3`, or `fetch first 3 rows only`, or even something else.